# HP Smart Array P410: Convert RAID10 to RAID1 OR remove disks from RAID10

Tags: raid, hp-smart-array, raid1, raid10

I have a server with two RAID10 arrays of 146GB disks. I'm trying to replace one RAID10 array of 146GB disks with RAID1 of two 2TB disks.
Since there are no free ports, I took out two disks from the array which I am going to replace. Now the status of my raid looks like this:

```
# /opt/hp/hpssacli/bin/hpssacli ctrl all show config

Smart Array P400 in Slot 1
   array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)
      logicaldrive 1 (273.4 GB, RAID 1+0, Interim Recovery Mode)

      physicaldrive 2I:1:1 (port 2I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, Failed)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:2 (port 2I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, Failed)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:3 (port 2I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:4 (port 2I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 146 GB, OK)

   array B (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)
      logicaldrive 2 (273.4 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:1:5 (port 1I:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:6 (port 1I:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:7 (port 1I:box 1:bay 7, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:8 (port 1I:box 1:bay 8, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
```

I want to use ports `2I:1:1, 2I:1:2` for the new RAID1 (to migrate the VM to the new array with minimal downtime). But I do not know how to untie them from the current RAID10. As I see two options:

1) Convert RAID10 to RAID1 (in the documentation I just found a mention that the new array could not be smaller than the current one)
To the command `"/opt/hp/hpssacli/bin/hpssacli ctrl slot=1 ld 1 modify raid=1"` I get an error:

```
Error: "raid=1" is not a valid option for logicaldrive 1

Available options are:
    0
    1 + 0 (current value)
    5
    6 (default value)
```

2) Remove the ports `2I:1:1, 2I:1:2` of RAID10.

However, I did not find instructions for both options.

What can be done in this situation? (Without taking into account the option of moving data to another server / external drive / etc.)

Comment: You removed the disks before asking the question?!?

Comment: Do not worry, this is a test server. On it, I check the options.

Comment: I've server Proliant DL180 G8.

I couldn't make that smart array stuff work as intended with Debian and/or Ubuntu. It was conflicting and could not recognize device.

So I've just disabled it and made Software RAID using mdadm.

Reason why I didn't solved hardware issue: it was easy to just remove bad disk drive from software array remotely, than going to data center to physically remove it.

Answer (score 7):

I don't participate here as much as I used to, but I see a problem with what you've done.

HP Smart Array controllers can accommodate SAS and SATA disks. However, you cannot have an array comprised of a mix of SAS and SATA disks.

HP never marketed a 2TB 2.5" SAS disk, so I'm assuming the 2TB drives you have are SATA. The 146GB disks are SAS. So... pulling two disks will not work because you can't join the new disks to the existing array.

You messed up. Put the two 146GB drives back in.

---

Other considerations:

You are probably using a 3rd party SATA disk. It will be downshifted to 1.5Gbps speeds on the Smart Array P400 controller.

The use of the a P400 controller means the server you're using is a G5 HP ProLiant, circa 2005-2007.

It's better to rebuild or use more modern hardware if possible.

Comment: Yes, the new drives are SATA. I'm not going to combine disks of different types, I want to eventually completely replace the RAID10 SAS on RAID1 SATA.